# How to save web page rendered video to mp4 - Diaporama

Tags: javascript, video

I have a set of images that I am creating a Diaporama video with so I can use the Ken Burns effect and glsl transitions. The video runs off of a json file that defines the timeline of images, their duration and the transition to the next image. The video is then rendered in the browser. I am looking for a way to save this rendered slideshow-type video as an actual mp4 file. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I've never seen a JavaScript to mp4 converter. Pretty sure there is no such thing, since JavaScript is a Programming Language, while mp4 is a file type. You could however run a program on your computer that captures video off of your screen. Once in video format you should be able to find a converter.

Comment: Actually chrome has some experimental WebRTC API which can capture [user's screen](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/desktopCapture). it  needs to be called from privileged code (from an extension). Then, you could save the stream as ogv and reencode it in mp4

Comment: Ya, that's what I thought. Just wanted to see if someone had written something to do that before. That's a good idea though. Or, I was considering opening the webpage through phantomjs and then rendering several images every second and looping all the images through ffmpeg to build the video.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. I am running a phantomjs runner.js script that opens the webpage and renders 25 images per second and then using ffmpeg to build an mp4 out of those images.

Phantomjs runner.js

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
page.viewportSize = { width: 640, height: 480 };

page.open('http://www.goodboydigital.com/pixijs/examples/12-2/', function () {
  setTimeout(function() {
    // Initial frame
    var frame = 0;
    // Add an interval every 25th second
    setInterval(function() {
      // Render an image with the frame name
      console.log("Image: " + frame);
      page.render('frames/image-'+(frame++)+'.png', { format: "png" });
      // Exit after 50 images
      if(frame > 50) {
        phantom.exit();
      }
    }, 25);
  }, 666);
});
```

And the command to run:

```
phantomjs runner.js && ffmpeg -y -start_number 0 -i frames/image-%d.png -c:v libx264 -r 25 -pix_fmt yuv420p output.mp4
```